# What is the proper way to dynamically create event handlers in JavaScript for many links?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-events

I am generating a number of links on a page. I want to add `onmouseover`, `onmouseout`, and `onclick` event handlers to the links after the DOM has loaded, i.e. use jQuery to loop through the links and attach the handlers. However the problem is each handler requires information specific to that link.

So as an example if I don't want to do it after the DOM has loaded it would look like:

```
<a href="" onmouseover="somefunc(1,100);"></a>
```

So in the above example, 1 and 100 is data read from a database and output on the page, and these need to be passed to the function. So how do I output this information for this link if I'm gonna attach an event handler at load time. Is this correct...?

```
<a href="" data="1,100">
```

In other words, I create my own attribute and later grab that information when attaching the event handler? Is that the standard way of doing it or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mention jQuery in your question (but not tagged)  I am going to assume it is a valid option.

If you are using jQuery > 1.4.3, jQuery will automaticlaly parse `data-*` attributes.

```
<a href="" data-number1="1" data-number2="100">
```

And in your jQuery click handler:

```
$("a").click(function(){
  var num1 =  $(this).data("number1");
  var num2 =  $(this).data("number2");
});
```

You can also store a json object in your `data-*` as well.

```
<a href="" data-numbers="{'num1: 1, 'num2': 2}">

$("a").click(function(){
  var numbers =  $(this).data("numbers");
  //numbers.num1 and numbers.num2
});
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to tag jquery. So basically this is the "standard" way. i.e. create "user-data" attributes and retrieve them when creating the handlers?

Comment: But I must say that I was looking to reduce the size of the code on the page by avoiding the verbosity of specifying onmouseover, onmouseout, and onclick handlers as the page is output. If I have to specify data-a, data-b, data-c on each link its not gonna help as much.

Comment: If you need additional information to describe the link it will be the easiest way and helps reduce the need for additional global variables, hidden fields when the data can be stored on the `<a/>` directly.

Comment: So maybe it would be smaller in terms of code size to pass a comma-delimited, for example, set of items as such data="1,100" and retrieve and split them later.

Comment: @dehlenbe, you can store a json object in your `data-*` attribute instead of having multiple attributes.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that if you're writing new markup, the easiest way would be to use the [HTML5 data-* attributes](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/):

```
<a href="" data-minVal="1" data-maxVal="100">Link Text</a>
```

And then you can use that in jQuery via the `data()` method (will not work with earlier versions of jQuery):

```
function someFunc(element, min, max){
    // Do something
}


$(function(){
    $('a').click(function(){
        var $this = $(this); // only create one jQuery object with this
        someFunc(this, $this.data('minVal'), $this.data('maxVal'));
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you specify which earlier versions of jQuery this won't work with, and why?

Comment: So basically this is the "standard" way. i.e. create "user-data" attributes and retrieve them when creating the handlers?

Comment: @Zimzat - Earlier versions of jQuery didn't have support for the data-* attributes (they're fairly new in the grand scheme of things) so the values wouldn't be automatically picked up.

Comment: Cool. Thought maybe there was some other more advanced way of doing this. I supposed I could get real fancy and give each link a unique ID, and output a javascript object that maps the ID to the parameters to the event handlers I will later attach.

Comment: I would recommend `var $this = $(this)` because it reads nicely and is unambigious.

Comment: Far better to give each object an id and put the data in an object with the id as a key. That way you are not binding the data to the element, nor constrained in regard to the structure of the data. That approach is a more general solution that will serve in other cases where you have more than one or two simple values to map.
In regard to the listeners, you may be better off putting them on an element higher in the DOM (delegating) and responding based on the event target. That way you only need a couple of listeners, not two or three per link.

Comment: @Justin Niessner: I think you missed the point of my question. I asked specifically what version. So, I've gone and looked it up: "As of jQuery 1.4.3 HTML 5 data- attributes will be automatically pulled in to jQuery's data object." http://api.jquery.com/data/